# Sporadic ftp 450 errors when uploading compressed file

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, zip

I have an 800Mb file that's getting compressed using the System.IO.Compression ZipArchive, thus:

```
using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(result, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    zip.CreateEntryFromFile(sourceFile, entryName);
}
```

The file compression is always successful. Once the file has been compressed, it's being uploaded to an ftp server with variable success. When the upload fails, it does so with the following error:

The remote server returned an error: (450) File unavailable (e.g., file busy).

Stack Trace:
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
at System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.IO.Stream.Close()
at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
at System.Net.CommandStream.Abort(Exception e)
at System.Net.CommandStream.CheckContinuePipeline()
at System.Net.FtpDataStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
at System.Net.FtpDataStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.IO.Stream.Close()

If I upload the uncompressed original file instead, that upload is always successful.

My suspicion is that the compressed file is somehow locked, or the ZipArchive instance may not have been disposed. I have tried alternative compression libraries with similarly inconsistent results. Any ideas?

Comment: Firewall or virus checker blocking zip files.  Try changing extension to piz and see if it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error turned out to be nothing to do with my initial suspicions, but was related to the ftp upload request. As a zip file is a binary format, it's necessary to set the request to use binary, and to avoid using a StreamReader to get the bytes from the file. My ftp code ended up like this:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri('ftpurl', filePath)));
request.Timeout = timeoutvalue;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.Proxy = new WebProxy();
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential('x','y');

byte[] encodedFileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
request.ContentLength = encodedFileContents.Length;

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.WriteTimeout = timeoutvalue;
    requestStream.Write(encodedFileContents, 0, encodedFileContents.Length);
}

using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
}
```

Comment: The documentation of FTPWebRequest states UseBinary is defaulted to true.  So was the issue only related to the StreamReader?